# notifyDataSetChanged and toMutableList don 't Works (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I am getting data from API http and using dataBinding and viewModel, all works but when I try to convert my list to mutableList and add All don't getting nothing, also try pass the data of simple way and working , the data is be there, the problem is that notifyDataSetChanged() don't do changes in my Adapter and I dont see nathing in the recyclerView.

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
     private lateinit var viewModel: MostPopularTVShowsViewModel
     private lateinit var activityMainBinding : ActivityMainBinding
     private  var tvShows: List<TVShow> = ArrayList()
     private lateinit  var tvShowAdapter:TVShowsAdapter

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)
         doInitialization()
     }

     private fun doInitialization(){
          activityMainBinding.tvShowRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(true)
          viewModel= ViewModelProvider(this).get(MostPopularTVShowsViewModel::class.java)
          tvShowAdapter= TVShowsAdapter(tvShows)
          activityMainBinding.tvShowRecycleView.adapter=tvShowAdapter
          getMostPopularTVShows()
     }

     private fun getMostPopularTVShows(){
         activityMainBinding.isLoading=true
         viewModel.getMostPopularTVShows(0).observe(this, { mostPopularTVShowsResponse ->
                 activityMainBinding.isLoading=false
                 if (mostPopularTVShowsResponse != null){
                     tvShows.toMutableList().addAll(mostPopularTVShowsResponse.tvShows)
                     //tvShows=mostPopularTVShowsResponse.tvShows
                     println("size is: "+tvShows.size)
                     tvShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                 }else{
                     Toast.makeText(this," NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                 }
             })
      }
  }
```

when i change `tvShows=mostPopularTVShowsResponse.tvShows` insted  `tvShows.toMutableList().addAll(mostPopularTVShowsResponse.tvShows)` the list gets the data  but notifyDataSetChanged dont working

this is my adapter

```
  class TVShowsAdapter(private val items: List<TVShow>): RecyclerView.Adapter<TVShowsAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
       private lateinit var layoutInflater: LayoutInflater

       override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
          layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
          val binding: ItemContainerTvShowBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
          layoutInflater, R.layout.item_container_tv_show,parent,false)
          return ViewHolder(binding)
       }
       override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)= holder.bind(items[position])

       override fun getItemCount()= items.size

      class  ViewHolder(private val itemContainerTvShowBinding: ItemContainerTvShowBinding): 
      RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemContainerTvShowBinding.root){
         fun bind (tvShow: TVShow){
             itemContainerTvShowBinding.tvShow=tvShow
             itemContainerTvShowBinding.executePendingBindings()
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually changing the data in the adapter. You're passing in a reference to the `tvShows` `ArrayList` when you create the adapter, so if you changed the contents of that list the adapter would be able to see it. But when you do

```
tvShows.toMutableList().addAll(mostPopularTVShowsResponse.tvShows)
```

you're creating a new, separate list by calling `toMutableList`, and you're adding stuff to **that**. `tvShows` is still the original, immutable `ArrayList` with nothing in it.

If you're going to do it this way, you need to make the list mutable from the beginning

```
val tvShows = mutableListOf<TVShow>()
```

then you can `clear` and `add` to it when you get new data.

Generally though, a better idea is to give the adapter some kind of `setData` function where you pass in a list, so it can update its own internal data set and notify itself about the change. That way the adapter manages it state itself, all your activity or fragment needs to do is pass it some new data

Comment: :0 is true, I believed that was are equals with only call the function toMutableList and now konow beacause i realy was confuce  , thank you so much